# Returning two strings in C++

Tags: c++, list, return, return-type

I am solving exercises for a C++ exam I have soon. Consider the following exercise:

> A travel agency uses lists to manage its trips. For each trip the agency registers its point of departure, point of arrival, distance and time/duration
>
> 1) Define the necessary structures to represent a list of trips
>
> 2) Write a function that, given integer i returns the point of departure and point of arrival of the trip in position i

Defining the structure is easy:

```
struct list{
    char departure[100];
    char arrival[100];
    double distance;
    double time;
    list* next = NULL;
};
```

My problem is the function. The actual work, to find the ith trip is easy. But how can I return the two char arrays/strings departure and arrival? If this were a question in my exam, I would have solved it like this:

```
typedef list* list_ptr;

list_ptr get_trip(list_ptr head, const int i){
    if(i<0 || head==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    for(int k = 0; k<i;k++){
        head = head->next;
        if(head==NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

I am returning a pointer to the list element. One then has to print departure and arrival. I could easily return just the departure or just the arrival by using a function with return type char*. How can I properly return 2 strings? 
I know that there is ways doing this using std::tuple, but I cannot use this as we haven't had it in the lecture(we only had the really basic stuff, up to classes).

Am I right that returning both strings is not possible without using additional libraries?

Cheers

Comment: [Containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)? Structures? [Pairs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)? [Tuples](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)?

Comment: You could also pass 2 string references to the function to fill in. And use `std::string` in stead of char arrays.

Comment: Look at [returning-several-values-from-a-function](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/487/returning-several-values-from-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, to start with, your `list` type has some problems. Don't use `char[]` in C++ unless you really, really have to (note: if you think you have to, you're probably wrong). C++ provides a standard library that is wonderous in its applications (well, compared to C), and you should use it. In particular, I'm talking about `std::string`. You're probably OK using `double` for distance and duration, although a lack of units means that you're going to have a bad time.

Let's try this:

```
struct Trip {
    std::string departure;
    std::string arrival;
    double distance_km;
    double duration_hours;
};
```

Now you can either use `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::slist`, or roll your own list. Let's assume the last.

```
class TripList {
  public:
      TripList() = default;

      // Linear in i.
      Trip& operator[](std::size_t i);
      const Trip& operator[](std::size_t i) const;

      void append_trip(Trip trip);
      void remove_trip(std::size_t i);

  private:
      struct Node {
          Trip t;
          std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
      };
      std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
      Node* tail = nullptr;  // for efficient appending
};
```

I'll leave implementation of this to you. Note that list and trip are separate concepts, so we're writing separate types to handle them.

Now you can write a simple function:

```
std::pair<string, string> GetDepartureAndArrival(const TripList& list, std::size_t index) {
    const auto& trip = list[index];
    return {trip.departure, trip.arrival};
}
```